# Why is my Silverlight application using so much un-managed memory?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have a rather simple Silverlight application, lately we've been having reports from users of the application crashing after several hours of use (4+).  We started digging into the application and noticed that the un-managed portion of memory being used by the application starts very high and continues to grow unchecked.  The other heaps seem to be managed just fine.  I've done a lot of research and even went as far removing all images from my application and the un-managed memory continues to grow.

I'm just confused at this point as to what exactly is consuming all the un-managed memory in my application and what I can do about it.  Here is a snapshot of my application after initial load, as you can see it's already using over 100MB of un-managed memory space.  I'm just looking for any guidance here on what objects could be in un-managed memory and what to do to reduce the amount of un-managed memory my application is using. Thanks!

[image: Ants Memory Snapshot]

I've taken another snapshot or two using the .NET Memory Profiler and it appears that the Kernel-HeapMemory is the largest chunk.  Not sure if this helps much but I thought I would post it anyway.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the WebBrowser component embedded in your Silverlight application?

Comment: No we aren't using the WebBrowser control.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be creating a lot of WriteableBitmaps?

Comment: We are using bitmaps, but not `WriteableBitmap` ones.

Comment: I will say though as a test we removed all the image code and we were still seeing the same issues.

Comment: Is this an in-browser or an out-of-browser SL app?

Comment: Well it can run as both, the memory leak doesn't appear to change based on whether the users run it in browser or out of browser.  Is there any way to view what exactly is contained within the un-managed portion of memory?

Comment: Maybe you are not calling enough Dispose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [CLR Profiler for Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released.aspx)? I've used it with some success in the past to troubleshoot memory issues.

Comment: This looks like a decent tool but it doesn't seem to be much use in profiling un-managed memory.  I don't seem to have any issues with the managed portion of my app.  I just can't seem to figure out why it continues to consume more and more un-managed memory.